# PHP how to create a textfile containing hyperlinks

Tags: php

Using PHP, creating hyperlinks on the screen is no problem using an ECHO statement.

Now that everything is working OK. I would like to save the output to a textfile in such a way that the hyperlinks still work when the file is opened in Word or excel.

Comment: What is your current code? What did you try yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`PHPWord`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) library.
With this library you can create Word documents in PHP including hyperlinks and other awesome stuff.

Hyperlink example:

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// Add hyperlink elements
$section->addLink('http://www.google.com', 'Best search engine', array('color'=>'0000FF', 'underline'=>PHPWord_Style_Font::UNDERLINE_SINGLE));
$section->addTextBreak(2);
$PHPWord->addLinkStyle('myOwnLinkStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'color'=>'808000'));
$section->addLink('http://www.bing.com', null, 'myOwnLinkStyle');
$section->addLink('http://www.yahoo.com', null, 'myOwnLinkStyle');


// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Link.docx');
?>
```